# Differential equation question to do with modelling gravity.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, asymptotics

Hi I am given two models for the gravity of earth, the first is with $x_3$ normal to the earth and is

$m\ddot{x}(t)=-mg(0,0,1)^T$

the other is with $x$ a distance vector from the centre of the earth and is

$m\ddot{x}=-GmM\frac{x}{|x|^3}$ with G being the gravitational constant.

I am asked to derive the first from the second by a formal expansion in $\frac{h_0}{R}$ and then show the expected accuracy is of the order $O(h_0/R)$

I have no idea how to start and have been looking at it for a while. I'm not even sure what it means by formally expanding by that. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Write $\vec x=\vec R_0+\vec r$. $\vec r$ is "small". Now write the Taylor development of $\frac{x}{|x|^3}$ in terms of $\vec r$.

Comment: Should I be expanding around $h_0/R$?

Comment: What is $h_0$? Is it $x_3-R$?